# firewalld zone settings don't survive a reboot

Tags: firewalld

[My previous adventures with firewalld and zones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318245/centos-7-firewalld-ignores-its-configuration-files/318254#318254) are incomplete.

- Specifying zones via `nmcli` *only*, verifying settings in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`, and verifying settings *not* in `/etc/firewalld/zones/` still puts both interfaces in the default zone on reboot.
- Specifying zones via `firewalld-cmd --permanent` *only*, verifying settings in `/etc/firewalld/zones/`, and verifying settings *not* in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` still puts both interfaces in the default zone on reboot.
- Specifying zones via both commands and verifying settings in both file sets still puts both interfaces in the default zone.

*Something* in the shutdown/startup process is resetting those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tracked [here](https://github.com/t-woerner/firewalld/issues/195) where I detailed a temporary fix on that issue but I'll write it here too:

I confirmed this behavior on CentOS 7.2.1511 and CentOS 7.3.1611.

No matter what combination of NetworkManager or firewalld commands that I used to keep the zones persistent, nothing seemed to work. I tried the "workaround" listed above and still nothing. Here's the workaround that I came up with for my use case.

I have the following interfaces that should be part of the corresponding zones persistently:

- enp0s3 - public
- enp0s8 - internal
- enp0s9 - external

I created a systemd unit file as a temporary fix to my troubles:
**/etc/systemd/system/myzones.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Zones
After=network.target network.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/bin/nmcli connection modify enp0s3 connection.zone public
ExecStart=/bin/nmcli connection modify enp0s8 connection.zone internal
ExecStart=/bin/nmcli connection modify enp0s9 connection.zone external

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I enabled the service and rebooted

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable myzones.service
# reboot
```

Only issue I ran into so far is if you try and restart the network.service when there are ifcfg-*.old files residing in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/. But a reboot will sort that out. I don't use the network service so I can live with this temporary fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have only ever tried setting `ZONE=` in the `ifcfg-*` files, which has always worked for me upon reboot.

It's not clear to me whether you have tried *only* editing the `ifcfg-*` files, but that's what's working for me, so I'm proposing it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen very similar behaviour on CentOS 7 and 8, when modifying interface zones using Ansible. The issue referred to in @user136881's answer has moved [here](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/195). Although supposedly fixed, I've found that when using Ansible's firewalld module to move an interface to a different zone, those zone changes revert after restarting firewalld.

As @charley comments, simply editing the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files works (requiring you to `systemctl restart NetworkManager`, to apply).

So I've stopped doing this:

```
- name: Set interface for internal zone
  ansible.posix.firewalld:
    interface: "{{ internal_nic }}"
    state: enabled
    zone: "{{ internal_zone }}"
    immediate: yes
    permanent: yes
```

and started doing this instead:

```
- name: Set interface for internal zone
  ansible.buitin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{ internal_nic }}
    regexp: '^ZONE='
    line: 'ZONE="{{ internal_zone }}"'
  notify: Restart NetworkManager
```