# firewalld still having trouble with stops and starts

Tags: firewalld, oracle-linux

My previous adventures with firewalld:

- [CentOS 7: Firewalld ignores its configuration files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318245/centos-7-firewalld-ignores-its-configuration-files)
- [firewalld zone settings don't survive a reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336757/firewalld-zone-settings-dont-survive-a-reboot)

Well, firewalld is still being weird across stops and starts. Here are the last several commands before I quit fighting for the day.

```
[root@[HOST] ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/firewalld
# firewalld command line args
# possible values: --debug
FIREWALLD_ARGS="--debug=10"

[root@[HOST] ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
Error: INVALID_ZONE

[root@[HOST] ~]# tail -10 /var/log/firewalld
2018-02-02 15:24:35 DEBUG2: Introspect()
2018-02-02 15:24:35 DEBUG2: config.Introspect()
2018-02-02 15:24:35 DEBUG2: config.Introspect()
2018-02-02 15:24:36 DEBUG2: config.Introspect()
2018-02-02 15:24:36 DEBUG1: getDefaultZone()
2018-02-02 15:24:36 DEBUG1: zone.getActiveZones()
2018-02-02 15:24:36 DEBUG1: getDefaultZone()
2018-02-02 15:24:36 DEBUG1: getZoneSettings()
2018-02-02 15:24:36 ERROR: INVALID_ZONE

[root@[HOST] ~]# egrep -i '^default' /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf
DefaultZone=work

[root@[HOST] ~]# systemctl stop firewalld

[root@[HOST] ~]# firewall-offline-cmd --get-default-zone
work

[root@[HOST] ~]# firewall-offline-cmd --list-all
work (active)
 target: DROP
 icmp-block-inversion: no
 interfaces: ens160
 sources:
 services: ssh nfs rpc-bind http https
 ports:
 protocols:
 masquerade: no
 forward-ports:
 source-ports:
 icmp-blocks:
 rich rules:

[root@[HOST] ~]# systemctl start firewalld

[root@[HOST] ~]# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone

[root@[HOST] ~]# yum list firewalld
Installed Packages
firewalld.noarch           0.4.4.4-6.el7           @ks-ol7_latest/7.3
```

At this point, I really I don't know how to continue investigating why `firewalld` just won't load its configuration. The layers of abstraction don't help. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2018-02-05:** Well, drat. Following up on the comment, I tried to duplicate the problem on CentOS and failed. This makes this an Oracle Linux problem, and their support is nil without a contract... More experimenting to follow.

Comment: Your previous adventures were on centos; why is this Q tagged as oracle Linux?

Comment: The first two were at home. The third is at work. Both are RHEL clones.